# How to change list content after applying a function in Python

Tags: python, list

I wrote a little program that inserts an element in a list. The program uses a binary search algorithm to find the spot where the new element should be allocated. I'm having trouble to change the original list content. What's wrong in my code?

```
def Insert(TAB,V):

    for i in range(0, len(TAB)):

        j, count = binarySearch(TAB,V)

        TAB = TAB[:j] + [V] + TAB[j:]

        return "index =",j,"comparisons =", count
```

Comment: `TAB.insert(j,V)`

Comment: Also, look into [the bisect module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html)

Comment: You want to either return `TAB` and have something that looks like `TAB = Insert(TAB, V)`, or do not change the returned value but replace `TAB = ...` with `TAB[:] = ...` to change the content of the list in place.

Comment: I want to replace the original list with the new list that includes the new element.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I can't use bisect module. It's an assignment from uni.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    TAB = TAB[:j] + [V] + TAB[j:]
```

This builds a new list and assigns it to the local variable `TAB`.  IF you expect to change the list in the calling program, then you have to operate directly on that list, not assign to its local avatar.

```
TAB.insert(j, V)
```

should do the job.